# Modules default.xml and minicart.phtml files conflict with custom theme

Tags: magento-2.1

In a module there a two files that conflict with a custom themes files:

- app\code\Magestore\Pdfinvoiceplus\view\frontend\templates\cart\minicart.phtml
- app\code\Magestore\Pdfinvoiceplus\view\frontend\layout\default.xml

Removing these two files fix the conflict. The problem is that if I update the module the files properly comes back unless I remember to delete them. I want to ensure it is a permanent fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you keep your magento code in a git repository, than you can simply add those two files to .gitignore and they won't get deployed on your production server, no matter if they exist locally or not.

I'm not really sure if there is a clean way to remove files that are integral part of custom extensions. Less clean would be a script (bash script for example) that removes those files, but you would need to run it manually after each update or automatically using cron... but I strongly not recommend those ways.